# How to integrate $\frac{x^{2}\log {\sin x}}{1+x^{6}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I recently stumbled upon a question
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{m-1}\log^{a}x}{1+x^n}dx$$
I was able to evaluate it,but I am curious if there exists a closed form for,
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x^{2}\log{\sin x}}{1+x^6}dx$$
It numerically evaluates to -0.1392432458.

My attempt-

$$\int \frac {x^2}{1+x^6}dx=\frac13 \int \frac {d(x^3)}{1+x^6}=\frac13 \arctan {x^3}$$
Then,by applying integration by parts,
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x^2\log\sin x}{1+x^6}dx=-\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac13\arctan {x^3} \cot x dx$$.But now I'm stuck.

Comment: Where did you stumble upon the integral - what context? That sort of information would make this a better post.

Comment: The question I stumbled upon had $\log x$ instead of $\log \sin x$.

Answer (score -2):

The integration you want to solve doesn't have an analytical solution, so using integration by parts won't help you much. However, you can use a number of numerical methods out there for approximating integrals.

Comment: How do we know that it doesn't have any analytical solution?

Comment: using  matlab or mathmatic